# Calculus problem regarding graph of derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

[image]

This is from GRE Math test, it is clear that $f(0)<f(2)>f(4)$, but how can I determine the remaining relation?

Also, can you recommend me materials relating to these kinds of problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

- from 0 to 2, $f$ is increasing
- from 2 to 4, $f$ is decreasing
- area under the graph for $f’$ between 0 and 2 is greater

Comment: Use FTC for $f(x)=\int_0^x f’(t)dt$

Comment: @LongLêThiên we have $f(2)=f(0)+A_1$ and $f(4)=f(0)+A_1-A_2$ with $A_1>A_2$, let make a sketch for $f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative at 2 is zero. To the left of 2 the derivative $f'$ is positive and to the right it is negative, which means increasing to the left and decreasing to the right.    So $f(2)$ is above the other values and the answer is C or E.  Any standard calculus book should be a good reference (see: First Derivative Test)
The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that the area from 0 to 2 is the same as $f(2)$.  There's not as much "negative area" between 2 and 4, so returning to $f(4)$ doesn't bring us down as far as $f(0)$ and the answer is C.

Comment: In choice E $f(2)$ is also above the other values.

Comment: There might just be some confusion here about inequalities.  For example, 1 < 3 > 2 should be written  1 < 2 < 3 or it might seem like 1 > 2.  These statements have to continue to make sense as you read from left to right. (Transitivity)

Comment: Steve-- If a<b>c is just to mean a<b and b>c, then it coud be any ordering with both a,b less than c. I agree inequalities *shoud* be written in consistent order, as in the choices of the GRE test.

Comment: coffeemath -- The reason for consistency is that otherwise you can't make sense of things like a < b > c < d.  Is it true that a < d?

Comment: Steve-- Guess max of 3 terms for an inconsistent string to imply anything at all. Also I've never seen inequalities strung together except "consistently" in texts/papers (meaning all in same direction).

Comment: You want inequalities to be transitive relations, which means that if a is related to b and b is related to c then a is related to c.  Equalities are also transitive, but many other relations (e.g. "friendship") are not.  If I am shorter than Bob and Bob is shorter than Ted, then I should be able to deduce that I am shorter than Ted, and my notation should reflect that.